# Insert a row for every hour in a date range

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with a StartDate column and an EndDate column. I need to insert into a new table a row for each hour in the date range of the above tables column.
The table I have looks like this 
StartDate                  EndDate
2017-10-25 19:00:00.000    2017-11-30 23:59:59.997
2017-10-26 13:00:00.000    2017-12-1 23:59:59.997

new table I need should look like this
Date           Hour
2017-10-25     19
2017-10-25     20
2017-10-25     21
2017-10-25     22
2017-10-25     23
2017-10-26     0
2017-10-26     1
2017-10-26     2
::::::::::     :
::::::::::     :
2017-11-30     22
2017-11-30     23

I am so lost, please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be done with an ad-hoc tally table in concert with a `CROSS APPLY`.

**Example**

```
Select Date = cast(D as date)
      ,Hour = datepart(HOUR,D) 
 From YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Top (DateDiff(HOUR,A.StartDate,A.EndDate)+1) D=DateAdd(HOUR,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)),A.StartDate) 
                 From  master..spt_values n1,master..spt_values n2
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
Date        Hour
2017-10-25  19
2017-10-25  20
2017-10-25  21
2017-10-25  22
2017-10-25  23
2017-10-26  0
2017-10-26  1
2017-10-26  2
2017-10-26  3
...
```

Comment: @MahithaAdmala Happy it helped